# How to parse out quotes from Text to work in a Javascript Confirm Message Box

Tags: javascript, c#

I am using the below code from the post below to show a JavaScript Confirm message based on data out of the database if the NavigationUrl is a '.com' This works EXCEPT when there are " quotes in the text.  Does anyone know how I can parse out the quotes or set the quotes properly so the JavaScript will display quotes in the message?

Here is the code on another post to actuall set up the onclick event on the hyper link etc:

http://forums.asp.net/p/2026622/5833708.aspx?p=True&t=635549629987458698

I've tried the following but when I click the link and it is set to contain a .com nothing happens. If I add text that has NO " quotes it works fine. The length of the text doesn't seem to matter:

C# Code when I am pulling the data from my database table:

```
    public string GetExternalDisclaimerText()
    {

        string externalDisclaimerText = context.TEST_GLOBAL.Where(tg => tg.ITEM_NM == "DISCLAIMER_TEXT").FirstOrDefault().ITEM_VALUE_TXT ?? "N/A";

        Debug.Write("before:  ");
        Debug.Write(externalDisclaimerText);

        externalDisclaimerText = externalDisclaimerText.Replace("\"", "\"");


        Debug.Write("after:  ");
        Debug.Write(externalDisclaimerText);

        return externalDisclaimerText ?? "N/A";
    }
```

Here is the text that does not work:

"I am pleased that we have been able to secure Coach Fisher as our head coach for the long term," athletic director Stan Wilcox said in a statement. "The commitment we are making to him is a reflection of the outstanding job he has done in leading our program to its current level of excellence. While we are delighted with the undefeated season this year and our upcoming appearance in the inaugural College Football Playoff, we began working on this new contract before the success of this past season was in full view. It is a great day for Florida State."

Comment: Why are you replacing " with "?

Comment: Oh - I need it to actually stay in there if possible.   The Confirm Message I need to display might contain quotes.   I just have to figure out how to parse it properly so the Javascript Confirm Message will fire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

```
 externalDisclaimerText = HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(externalDisclaimerText);
```

Answer (score 1):

2 issues, you should construct your search with like this -

```
myString = myString.replace(/\"/g, '\"');
```

adding the "g" at the end will replace all occurrences in the string.

You may also encounter other characters that break your code so you should look for a more robust escape feature.

Comment: I tried the following, but this did not work:                              externalDisclaimerText = externalDisclaimerText.Replace('\"', '\"');

Comment: externalDisclaimerText = externalDisclaimerText.Replace(/\"/g, '\"');